# Changing opacity of background images

Tags: html, css

I am doing a project on a country which consists of 3 html pages, and I have decided to put an image of the country's flag as the background image for each page.

I want to change the opacity of the background image, but each time i try and do it it changes the opacity of all the other content of the page - the text, headers, etc etc.

I have this line of code in my html:

```
<body background="flag.jpg">
```

and then in my css I have tried various things.  I have tried giving that tag an 'id' like flag, and then tried:

```
#flag {
        opacity: 0.2;
}
```

I have also tried just using 'background' instead of using 'id'.

I've been trying to figure it out for a while and can't get it, any advice will be appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/transparent-background-images/ as you cannot do that the way you attempted

Answer (score 2):

add another elementi with the `#flag` that will be the "background", for example

```
<body>
    <div id="flag"></div>
</body>
```

and an style with the flag

```
#flag {
    background-image: url("flag.jpg");
    background-position: top center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    opacity: 0.2;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: great, thank you very much!  so would the <body background> tag go in between the div tags?

Comment: body is the main html/website tag, u can apply styles to it, but personally i never touch the body, i made more containers inside... so the main parent is body. if u set styles to body (opacity, width, height, font styles, etc...), everything will be 
inherited to elements inside

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use opacity like this.

**One** solution is to use background-gradients like this:

```
background: linear-gradient(rgba(93, 41, 28, 0.8), rgba(93, 41, 28, 0.8)), url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/31044/pexels-photo-31044.jpg) fixed;
```

Comment: thats not very useful because u cant set a transparent background color... and another thing, if u set opacity to body, everything inside will have that opacity...